# Debugger Error

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, crash

I have a problem On 3GS Iphone.When i deploying a application on phone then it exited with 
following error.

"The Debugger has exited due to signal 11 (SIGSEGV).The Debugger has
exited due to signal 11 (SIGSEGV)."

After that application not started & it installed on phone  but when phone disconnected then it works.
So Pls. help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app crashed because you accessed memory that you hadn't allocated. The next step is to look at the stack trace and your source code to see where you did this.

[This page in Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html) gives an overview of debugging iPhone applications.